# js and xregexp attempting to include an additional newline in group match

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript

My psuedo coffeescript code:

```
xre = require('xregexp').XRegExp
bodyRe = xre(
  '\\*\\s(?<body>.*)', 'img')
xre.forEach @blob, bodyRe, (match, i) ->
  console.log match
```

Data that I want to match:

```
  * Fix threaded execution
  * More fixes
    Spans additional lines  # <- Include this and any additional lines
  * Tartar sauce
```

Result:

```
['Fix threaded execution',
 'More fixes',
 'Tartar sauce']
```

What's expected:

```
['Fix threaded execution',
 'More fixes\nSpans additional lines',
 'Tartar sauce']
```

So far this captures all lines starting with * but I want to match from the first * to the end of a line where * is not present.

An example would be nice, however, I'm more interested in what I should be researching to get a better handle on this particular use case.

Comment: What's the problem with it? What's it matching that it shouldn't? What's it not matching that it should?

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the result and whats expected

Comment: I suggest you put solid qualifications for what you want to match in your question or you may get some answers you don't want. Right now, it just seems like you want to match everything between two `*`.

Comment: Was the result and whats expected not enough?

Comment: Well, it would just be more helpful if you were to say something like: *"I want to match from the first `*` to the end of a line where `*` is not present."* Something that describes the regex you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Anonymous, updated, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Yes, that's much clearer. But, your question about what you should be researching is somewhat broad and not appropriate for Stack Overflow. I suggest you read [how to best ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As for research, there are some excellent resources about regular expressions that I suggest you check out. You should be able to find them by just searching regex or regular expressions on Google. Some basic concepts should help you solve this problem for sure. Try looking at character classes to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of such behavior is the dot symbol does not match line breaker, so you should change you regexp to something like that:

```
'\\*\\s(?<body>[^\\*]*)'
```